# Unable to run a batch file(which calls a vbscript(which executes qtp script)) on a remote machine using psexec

Tags: psexec

The scenario is like below :

abc.vbs file - contains call to QTP,which executes test scripts.
xyz.bat file - contains call to abc.vbs

when i run xyz.bat in remote machine in a command prompt,it works perfectly.

When i run using PSExec on my local machine with the following command,it wont run.

E:/FolderName>PSExec -i //remote machine name -u (username) -p (password) complete path of file/xyz.bat

It says file exited with error code 0.

But in remote server nothing would have happened.

Can somebody help me in this case ??

Comment: try running with admin rights

Comment: I am trying with admin rights. But still the same thing exists.